# Enable Spring Boot 2.0 Actuator Endpoints With JWT security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-boot-actuator

First, I'm new to Spring Boot Framework. I have been working on actuator for few days now and was able to set up endpoints to monitor the system. How ever when I integrate JWT for the security all my actuator endpoints got broke.

How can I disable JWT security for actuator endpoints which is on top of spring boot security?
Following is my application.yml file properties.

```
management:
  endpoint:
    metrics:
      enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: health, metrics
```

Comment: Do you use the same port for Actuator and your main application? If you simply want to disable security for Actuator `management.security.enabled=false` should do.

Comment: @dur this property was removed in Spring Boot 2 - the equivalent now is management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

Answer (score 5):

If you do have dependency on Spring Security you have to configure (disable) it specifically for the `/actuator` endpoints.

You have to extend [`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html) as described in the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/helloworld-boot.html#securing-the-application) and permit all access to the desired endpoints. Check out this Spring Boot 2 Security example [Disabling actuator security but not user-defined endpoints](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Security-2.0#disabling-actuator-security-but-not-user-defined-endpoints).

This is how you can disable the security to the actuator endpoints:

```
@Configuration
public class ActuatorSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatcher(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
    }

}
```

The [custom security example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Security-2.0#custom-security-example) is also useful.

Answer (score 1):

Complementing hovanessyan answer, if you are using @EnableResourceServer on your configuration, you also will need add the @Order(-1) annotation to your "ActuatorSecurity" class.

See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50048440/9697259